# Creating a google map without giving the user a full list of locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using a Google Map to display a list of addresses across the country.

What troubles me is that anyone clicking "`view source`" can have the list, including coordinates and name :

```
placemarker(50.3161,4.93133,'store1', 'address1');
placemarker(48.6599,2.32982,'store2', 'address2');
placemarker(43.4512,5.41388,'store3', 'address3');
placemarker(48.8832,1.46008,'store4', 'address4');
...
```

Is there a way to display markers on the map while making it harder to extract the full list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[obfuscate your code](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm):

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('3(9.b,4.e,\'c\',\'0\');3(6.a,2.7,\'8\',\'0\');3(d.f,5.k,\'i\',\'0\');3(6.j,1.g,\'h\',\'0\');',21,21,'address4|||placemarker|||48|32982|store2|50|6599|3161|store1|43|93133|4512|46008|store4|store3|8832|41388'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Nice obfuscator, thanks for the link ! Unfortunately the list is dynamically generated, so I'd have to write my own obfuscator :|

Comment: Could you supply the list of coordinates with AJAX rather than inline JS?

Comment: Like calling a .php page with jQuery.ajax() ? Do you mean using a parameter, so that not all markers are loaded at any given time ?

Comment: I was thinking just passing all the markers back from a .php file should make it harder (but not impossible) for people to figure out the coordinates.